# How to get data from rdf in haskell rdf4h

Tags: haskell, rdf, linked-data

Im trying to get the capital of the country from rdf using rdf4h

```
Right (rdf::TriplesGraph) <- parseURL (XmlParser Nothing Nothing) "http://live.dbpedia.org/data/Spain.rdf"

let c = query rdf (Just (UNode "http://live.dbpedia.org/resource/Spain"))  (Just (UNode "http://live.dbpedia.org/property/capital")) Nothing
```

but it returns empty list

I can see that it has triple with

```
"ns3:string"
```

predicate, instead of

```
"http://live.dbpedia.org/property/capital"
```

after parsing URL,

How should I resolve this or am I missing some other method?

Edit: found this function

```
uniqTriplesOf :: rdf -> Triples
```

which does expand the namespaces, now the question is how can I query this rdf by full uris

Comment: What's the exact data you are are querying? - can you show us the relevant triples (just the ones that ought to match your query)?

Comment: @DNA I want to get "http://live.dbpedia.org/resource/Madrid", by "http://live.dbpedia.org/resource/Spain" and "http://live.dbpedia.org/property/capital"

Comment: Note that the data contains both an `ns2` prefix, mapped to `http://live.dbpedia.org/property/` and an `ns3` prefix, mapped to `http://live.dbpedia.org/ontology/` and the Spain resource has both an `ns2:capital` and an `ns3:capital` property (both pointing to Madrid)

Comment: @DNA but I know I need this http://live.dbpedia.org/property/capital one, and cannot get real uri only "ns3:string" thing

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a shortcoming in the rdf4h API. For now, the way to write your query is:

```
Right (rdf::TriplesGraph) <- parseURL
           (XmlParser Nothing Nothing)
           "http://live.dbpedia.org/data/Spain.rdf"
let c = query rdf
          (Just (UNode "http://live.dbpedia.org/resource/Spain"))
          (Just (UNode "ns2:capital"))
          Nothing
```

I'll look to add a function to the API:

```
queryExpanded :: rdf -> Maybe Node -> Maybe Node -> Maybe Node -> Triples
```

Which would, when its implemented in the future, let you write:

```
let c = queryExpanded rdf
          (Just (UNode "http://live.dbpedia.org/resource/Spain"))
          (Just (UNode "http://live.dbpedia.org/property/capital"))
          Nothing
```